# UITableView inconsistencies

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView that loads inconsistently.

1. When it first loads, I scroll up and down the table, it works perfectly
2. While on that view, I hit home button, then immediately touch the app to relaunch it
3. The view loads and the four cells of the table that are showing load fine
4. I then scroll down the UITableView and the cells begin to disappear, my log shows that parts of the array are null
5. I then hit home and immediately relaunch the app, the four cells of the table that are in view  are completely restores and look correct.
6. I then scroll down again and they dissaper, the log again says they are null.

Why would the UITableView be restored each time on launch but the array that makes the table be null? Why does entering background make the tableArray null? Can someone help me with where to look on this progression?

Comment: What does that view controller do when its view is unloaded?

Comment: Each VC is a tab in a tabBarController. I don't know if/when they are unloaded.

Comment: But assuming they do, is there anything in their `viewWillUnload:` or `viewDidUnload:` methods that might affect your data?

Comment: no, I don't use either method in that viewController. just viewDidLoad

Comment: One last shot....  Does `viewDidLoad:` re-initialize your array?

Comment: I check to see if the array is null and if it is, ask for the data again

Comment: It was a separate data problem. You were on the right track...

Comment: May be array is declared as weak attribute